# Cannot ping while using Fiddler (Request Timed Out)

Tags: ping, fiddler

As the title states, I cannot ping while using Fiddler.  When I attempt to ping a website (For example "google.com") it will resolve the URL into an IP address, but it just gives a "Request timed out." message.

C:\Users\Owner>ping google.com

Pinging google.com [74.125.21.100] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 74.125.21.100:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss)

I can surf the web, I can watch Netflix, I can get on Teamspeak, but I cannot ping a URL, and I cannot connect to the update server for a game that I play (I noticed the ping issue when I tried to ping the update server, but I cannot ping any server).  The only pings I have successfully been able to perform are "localhost", "loopback", and "127.0.0.1"

Answer (score 0):

This isn't about Fiddler; Fiddler is a HTTP proxy, and it doesn't change anything to do with ICMP packets used by the ping command.

My guess is that your firewall is blocking ICMP.

In the black QuickExec box below Fiddler's Web Sessions list, type

`!ping google.com`

and hit Enter. What do you see?

Comment: 01:25:30:5087 Pinged 'google.com'.
 Final Result: TimedOut

As a note, I am tethered to my phone (Acting as my router), and on the phone I can ping just fine, but I cannot ping on the computer.

Comment: That strongly suggests that your phone isn't willing to act as a gateway for ICMP from the PC, meaning it is acting as a firewall.

Comment: I guess so, but it just started having issues earlier this week after using it the exact same way for almost a year.